# ngrx routing when action is dispatched

Tags: angular, ngrx

I'm using ngrx in order to store my user state. With user state I mean an `IUser` class object with some user properties.

I've set several action (`'USER_LOGIN', 'USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS' and 'USER_LOGJN_FAILED'`).

Currently, when an `USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS` is dispatched, the reducer assigns the new user information to my `IStore.user` ngrx store field. When it's changed:

```
this.user$ = this.store$.select(state => state.user);
this.userSub = this.user$.subscribe(
    (user: IUser) => {
        if (user.id != null)
           this.router.navigate(['/app']);
    }
);
```

As you can see, I only check if the state of my changed user is `user.id != null` and then I navigate to my `/app` route.

Is there to do it using a mor elegant way. For example,

1. without using a explicit subscription to my `IStore.user` field?
2. Could I navigate straightforwardly to a route when an action (`'USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS'`) is dispatched?
3. Could I focus all this behavior in a single injectable?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can do this in a more elegant way.
Let's review it step by step :)

**1) Use `filter` from rxjs instead of `if` statement**

```
this.userSub = this
  .user$
  .filter((user: IUser) => user.id !== null)
  .subscribe((user: IUser) => this.router.navigate(['/app']));
```

**2) Avoid to handle subscriptions one by one**
*(there's a great article from Ben Lesh on [Medium](https://medium.com/@benlesh/rxjs-dont-unsubscribe-6753ed4fda87) about that)*

```
private componentDestroyed$: new Subject<void>();

ngOnInit() {
  this
    .user$
    .filter((user: IUser) => user.id !== null)
    .takeUntil(this.componentDestroyed$)
    .subscribe(_ => this.router.navigate(['/app']));
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.componentDestroyed$.next();
  this.componentDestroyed$.complete();
}
```

**3) Do not apply your logic inside the `subscribe`**

Use a `do` or a `map` to handle your logic, before the subscribe.
- `do` if you simply need to do something
- `map` if you want to return the result

```
this
  .user$
  .filter((user: IUser) => user.id !== null)
  .takeUntil(this.componentDestroyed$)
  .do(_ => this.router.navigate(['/app']))
  .subscribe();
```

*(CF next part for the "why")*

**4) Use "selectors" if you want to re-use or export some logic**

If I had to make some guesses on your code, I imagine that your user$ is the current user. The one connected right ? And you may have to copy all that code in other part of your app to find this user again.

That a good use case for a "*[selector](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ComputingDerivedData.html)*".
*(I exported 2 functions here so this code can be AOT friendly).*

```
export function _getCurrentUser(store: Store<any>) {
  return store$
    .select(state => state.user)
    .filter((user: IUser) => user.id !== null);
}
```

And then in your component :

```
this
  .store$
  .let(getCurrentUser)
  .takeUntil(this.componentDestroyed$)
  .do(_ => this.router.navigate(['/app']))
  .subscribe();
```

---

**In the end we have**

a `user.selector.ts` :

```
export function getCurrentUser(store: Store<any>) {
  return store$
    .select(state => state.user)
    .filter((user: IUser) => user.id !== null);
}
```

a `component` :

```
private componentDestroyed$: new Subject<void>();

ngOnInit() {
  this
    .store$
    .let(getCurrentUser)
    .takeUntil(this.componentDestroyed$)
    .do(_ => this.router.navigate(['/app']))
    .subscribe();
}

ngOnDestroyed() {
  this.componentDestroyed$.next();
  this.componentDestroyed$.complete();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do to tidy is use the .skipUntil operator on your subscription as follows;

```
this.user$ = this.store$.select(state => state.user);
this.user$.skipUntil( user => user.id );
this.userSub = this.user$.subscribe(
    (user: IUser) => {
           this.router.navigate(['/app']);
    }
);
```

then you don't need the conditional inside the subscription.

Comment: i'm also sure you could use an effect to call a navigation action on your router state, however I haven't used the router state like this myself yet.